# Excel conditional formatting with multiple cell comparison

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

So what I need to do is highlight rows based on cell comparisons.

```
for example is A2 = D2 AND E2 Make it green.
but if A2 = D2 OR E2 but not both make it yellow
and if A2 <> D2 OR E2 make it red.
```

is that kind of comparison possible?

EDIT for Gordon K:

[image: Format Box]

[image: Examples Columns A- E B is white]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

Make all the cells red, then...

[image]
[image]

Check the order the formatting is applied is correct:

[image]

Gives you:

[image]

If you want the whole row to change colour, then just change the "Applies to" box to cover all the columns of interest.

Comment: This method of checking for the 'red' rule is a good one; using Excel's internal logic that it will only conditionally format if one of the rules is met, this saves you some time.

Comment: Ok so I've put in the rules as suggested. However, I am getting strange results. For example: A = 03151996NA, D+E = 36275 but the cell is still green when it should be red. or A+D+E are all 5225 and the cell is yellow when it should be green.

Comment: The order in which the rules are applied is important and you need to tick the "Stop if True" box. I'd need to see a screenshot of your conditional formatting rule and the incorrect behaviours to work out why the first case is going wrong.

Comment: I have added the images to my original post

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible - this requires 3 separate conditional formatting rules:

(1) =and(A2=D2,A2=E2)   [set rule to highlight GREEN]
This works because the And function requires each argument (separated by commas) to be True, for the entire function to return true. If either argument is false, then the And function returns false.

(2) =and(or(A2=D2,A2=E2),D2<>E2)    [set rule to highlight yellow]

This combines the And function above with an Or function. Or returns True if any one of its arguments is true. So first, this formula checks whether EITHER A2=D2 or A2=E2. But, if that happens, A2 might equal both results. So, we need to say that the Or statement needs to return True, but also, we need to make sure that D2 doesn't equal E2. If it does, then A2 = both of them. "<>" means "does not equal" in Excel (often represented in other languages by "!=").

(3) =and(A2<>D2,A2<>E2)    [set rule to highlight red]

You should by now see how this one works.

Note that you should really take time to look through each of the boolean functions and understand how they work; without a fundemental understanding of boolean functions it will be hard to move forward with your class (which I assume this is for).

Comment: To clarify, if you want to apply this over multiple columns, change the formatting to have an ABSOLUTE reference to the column number, and a RELATIVE reference to the row number. This means that for each column to the right you move, it will keep the same column, but for each row down you move, it will use the cells one row down. Do this by putting a "$" to the left of each column. ie: "A2<>D2" becomes "$A2<>$D2".